# How do I vary the range of output of a variable voltage divider

Tags: voltage-divider

A voltage divider follows a fet in an audio booster. The pot in this divider is 250K and I'm reading a range of 0 to 6vac in my circuit. Because I want to build this into a volume pedal I'd like to be able to raise the lowest possible voltage and reduce the maximum possible voltage of this arrangement. Both of these variations to be on their own pot. Could somebody please help me to work out a solution to this? Thanks. [image: Booster Output Circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUuGP7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Add series resistors on either "side" of the pot. If you want to change these parameters during use, substitute potentiometers (wired as rheostat with the wiper tied to one side) for the resistors.

These will reduce the range of the attenuation. The upper end of the range is determined by the "top" series resistance (R3) and the lower end by R2.

However, something to note:

Presumably, this circuit will be driving a load (i.e. it will be connected to *something*). That *something* has an input impedance. As drawn (and as in the circuit above), you have a 250kΩ pot as an output attenuator. This will give you a large output impedance, and so connecting to an input may give you a lot of attenuation. It is for this reason that output attenuators are typically 10k or 25k pots, rather than 250k pots. I included a load impedance in my schematic, you can simulate the circuit and adjust R4 to be a more realistic load and observe what effect it has on the output signal.

If you have a load of 10k, which is not unheard of in the audio world, your output levels will suffer, as the output impedance of the attenuator (particularly when at middle range) is far greater than the input impedance of the load.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add a 250K pot at the top of your existing 250K pot. That would set your maximum volume. Another 250K pot below your existing 250K pot would set your minimum volume.
 For both pots tie the center wiper to the bottom tap on the pot. If it works in reverse just move the center tap to the other side of the same pot